# htaccess rewrite breaks relative paths

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an htaccess file which maps

```
http://www.myserver.com/home/
```

to

```
http://www.myserver.com/index.php?section=home
```

This part works fine. The issue I am facing now is, all my images and css reside in a sub-folder named assets, i.e.

```
http://www.myserver.com/assets/images/
```

```
http://www.myserver.com/assets/css/
```

etc.

After redirection the browser will look for the files under

```
http://www.myserver.com/home/assets/images/
```

which causes things to break, as this is not a valid path.

I have been able to add another rewrite that maps the above to the correct sub-folder, however, Firebug shows that the images are residing in:

```
http://www.myserver.com/home/assets/images/
```

I know it's not really a problem, after all, my  images and css are loading just fine with this rule. 
I'm just curious as to how I could make the path shown to be the actual path, which is:

```
http://www.myserver.com/assets/images/
```

Pasting my htaccess file below. Thank you very much beforehand.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/assets/(css|images|js)/(.*)$ /assets/$2/$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /index.php?section=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that you didn’t consider that relative URLs are resolved on the base URI that is the URI of the HTML document the reference is used in. So a relative URI path like `assets/images/` in an HTML document with the URI path `/home/` is resolved to `/home/assets/images/` instead of `/assets/images/`.

You cannot change this with mod_rewrite as URI resolution is done by the client and not by the server. The only solutions are:

- change the base URI using the [`BASE` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-BASE) (note that this affects *all* relative URI);
- using absolute URI paths, e.g. `/assets/images/` instead of a relative `assets/images/`;
- adjusting the relative URI path, so references in `/home/` are adjusted to `../assets/images/` to reflect the path depth.

Comment: I was trying not to have to go the path of converting all my relative paths to absolute, but alas, I might just have to now. Then again, I completely forgot about the <pre>BASE</pre> tag! That worked like a charm. Thanks Gumbo, appreciate it.

Comment: @irot: Again, note that changing the base URI using `BASE` affects *all* relative URIs and not just those with relative paths.

Comment: It also affects anchor tags with hashes. Any anchor tag with an href attribute like "#content" will resolve to the base URL and not the current page.

Comment: +1 new to all this, and was wondering why this was happening. This is for a file in the root of the site, and a simple `<BASE href="/">` fixed the assets issue.

Comment: Just for reference, the absolute path is relative to the `DocumentRoot` set up for the host in apache

Comment: CORS problem with <BASE

Answer (score 10):

Add this line `<BASE href="http://www.yoursitename.com/">` to your page inside the `<head>` tag as the following:

```
<head>
        <title>Your site title</title>
        <BASE href="http://www.yoursitename.com/">
....
</head>
```