# Pretty URLs with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [htaccess rewrite breaks relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899991/htaccess-rewrite-breaks-relative-paths)

I am hoping someone can help me. I am trying to set my website to use pretty URLs.

I currently have a few htaccess commands which hide my subdomain folder containing all my php files as well as a command to change my protocol from http to https and vice versa. The pretty url is proving to be difficult. I want to do it solely by htaccess and not php. I managed to write a command which worked but non of my css or javascript worked after that.

```
# Redirect from website.com to www.website.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect url to www
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /defaultfolder/([^\ ]+)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ defaultfolder/error.php [L]

#this section hides the defaultfolder, tried to modify this code here to make friendly urls.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.website.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !defaultfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !images/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ defaultfolder/$1\.php [L]

#https redirect
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/defaultfolder/)(login|securepages|pages)\.php
RewriteRule ^defaultfolder/(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [R,L]

#http redirect
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/defaultfolder/)(index|nonsecure pages)\.php
RewriteRule  ^defaultfolder/(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: (With a more informative question title, you might find more exact duplicates though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> non of my css or javascript worked after that.

This is probably a relative/absolute path issue. When you change the path of the URL, relative links are going to break because the base has changed. You can either add a couple of rules to point requests for css/js to the right places, or try adding the correct base using the `<base>` tag in the header of your pages. Something like:

```
<base href="/">
```

Otherwise you may have to rewrite the way css and js get resolved. Say for instance, you have all of your styles in `/css/` and all your scripts in `/js/`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/
RewriteRule ^(.*\.css)$ /css/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/
RewriteRule ^(.*\.js)$ /js/$1 [L]
```

---

```
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" media="all"/>
```

> and this is in the main subfolder

So that would mean you need a rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/defaultfolder/
RewriteRule ^(css|js)/(.*)\.(css|js)$ defaultfolder/%1/%2.%3 [L]
```

Comment: I recommend against the usage of `<base href>` - in my experience, while it seems a shortcut/helper at first, more than once I suffered from its effects later. I remember Joomla team wanting to get rid of theirs `<base>` tag, but having difficult to do it without breaking backwards compatibility, plus other things. So, at least, be careful when using it.

Comment: Thanks, is there away to write this in a single set of command to be able to hide my default subdomain as well as have pretty urls?

Comment: @JamesBondInBlack What's an example of a css/js link in you pages and where is it supposed to be on your site?

Comment: <head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" media="all"/>

Comment: and this is in the main subfolder

Comment: @JamesBondInBlack added an edit to answer