# htaccess pretty urls not working on some pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, pretty-urls

Some help needed with my htaccess pretty urls. I uploaded this htaccess file to my public html:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It works for the most part, but for pages that I created after the htaccess file was uploaded, it doesn't work. How do make ALL pages with out the file extension?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I don't think it is an issue with a path or subdomain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pretty URLs with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219074/pretty-urls-with-htaccess)

Comment: That post seems like a different issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a folder named girlscouts. If yes try to changing girlscouts.php to other name it should work.

Comment: I renamed the subfolder and it still shows a 404... this is such a complicated issue