# My .htaccess is looks good, but it is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have been breaking my head against the wall for days, and I know I am closer but I don't how to make this .htaccess works.

**I have this link:**

```
http://rebateninja.com?page=reviews&id=B005KMDV9A&review=Shark-Navigator-Professional-Lift-Away-Vacuum-Clea
```

**And I want to call it like this:**

```
http://rebateninja.com/reviews/B005KMDV9A/Shark-Navigator-Professional-Lift-Away-Vacuum-Clea
```

**My htacess is have this:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&review=$3 [L]
```

**But the page is full of 404 errors trying to point to non-existing resources like this:**

```
http://rebateninja.com/reviews/B005KMDV9A/css/960.css
```

instead of

```
http://rebateninja.com/css/960.css
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Indent 4 spaces or highlight code blocks and click the `{ }` button to format as code. The links won't be converted to real hyperlinks then.

Comment: How are you linking to your css file? '`../css/960.css`', '`http://rebateninja.com/css/960.css`' or '`/css/960.css`'?

Comment: Generally the way to make sure real resources are not rewritten is `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` both placed right before the `RewriteRule`

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's true, your `.htaccess` is right ...

May be, change `[L]` with `[NC]`
and your ocde look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&review=$3 [NC]
```

hOPE IT HELP

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your actual site the links to your css files are `css/960.css` so they are being looked for in the current folder, so `http://rebateninja.com/reviews/B005KMDV9A/` rather than the root.

Check this post out - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3900018/1791606

Answer (score 0):

Your links are relative instead of absolute. This means the browser tries to guess what the base URI is and when the URL the browser accesses looks like:

```
http://rebateninja.com/reviews/B005KMDV9A/Shark-Navigator-Professional-Lift-Away-Vacuum-Clea
```

That means any relative URLs in the content will have the base `/reviews/B005KMDV9A/` attached to it, so if the relative link looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/960.css">
```

The resulting request is made for `http://rebateninja.com/reviews/B005KMDV9A/css/960.css`. You need to either use absolute links or add a:

```
<base href="/">
```

in the header of your pages.