# URL rewriting with spaces

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a url like this :

```
www.qwerty.in/details.php?vendor_id=1&name=abcd%20cafe
```

I am trying to conver this like below with the help of .htaccess file :

```
www.qwerty.in/1/abcd-cafe
```

I am trying the below but unfortunately its not working . can anyone help

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ details.php?vendor_id=$1&name=$2
```

Comment: Is that the URL of the php page in which you have to write your script? I mean, do you have those values in the GET array?

Answer (score 2):

You character must allow space as well:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-\s]+)$ details.php?vendor_id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

I have used `\w`, which is same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Answer (score 0):

The following rule will convert your URL from `www.qwerty.in/details.php?vendor_id=1&name=abcd%20cafe` to `www.qwerty.in/1/abcd%20cafe`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /details.php?vendor_id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

It it much more generalized however, and will convert the first two parameter values even if they are not `vendor_id` or `name`. If this is not the behavior you'd prefer, have a look at [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27079018/2788872).

Converting a space to underscore can be achieved using:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\s(.*)$ $1_$2 [N]
```

Also, don't forget to ensure the rewrite engine is online:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

---

If you want to further experiment with these rules, I'd recommend a website I recently discovered: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

Comment: Weisz : thanks ...its working but now its not taking the existing css of the page..any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: You might use absolute paths instead of relative ones; if your website resides in the root directory, this should be easy. Instead of going into details, please have a look at this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899991/htaccess-rewrite-breaks-relative-paths

Comment: How are you referencing the .css file (eg.: `link` tag's `rel` attribute), and where is it located in the directory tree?

Comment: I am referencing like this : <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main1.css" />

Comment: `./css/main1.css` <- the `./` means 'current folder'. What happens if you remove the dot but keep the slash: `href="/css/main1.css"`? Also, in my previous comment I meant `href`, not `rel`. (ಠ_ಠ)