# Weird bug with php in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have webpage kallavere.edu.ee
this page like any others is made up from php files like index.php

while i were working with .htaccess i spot a weird bug,
for some reasons you can do something like that: kallavere.edu.ee/index.php/1231(random stuff)
if you do so, it will display you the page, but because of the wrong path, it won't link with css and picture files - so you will see only naked HTML.

so question is: why/how is that possible, and how i could fix that(not allow user to use file as folder in directory)?

I tried to search something about that in google but didn't find anything and i dont have enough knowledge about mod_rewrite.

Comment: What does your `.htaccess` have in it?

Comment: currently there is no .htaccess at all, but before i had: `RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)*$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess rewrite breaks relative paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899991/htaccess-rewrite-breaks-relative-paths)

Comment: It looks like that i have different problem from above one. Right now this page doesn't have rewrite at all, but problem still exists

Comment: Have you checked the Network tab of your browser's developer tools when doing a request?

Comment: well it writes under the GET text that is after _kallavere.edu.ee/index.php/_