# HT Access redirect to single file

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect:
https://www.example.com/whatever-part-is-coming-after-the-url
to
https://www.example.com/index.php?url=whatever-part-is-coming-after-the-url

without changing the request in the address bar.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

If I use this, it works for URL's like https://example.com/foo, but not for https://example.com/foo/bar (all relative urls, like content/styles.css are now foo/content/styles.css, which gives 404 error).

When I add

```
[R=301]
```

The redirection is done right, but it shows an 'ugly' URL.
Is there a way to have both?

Comment: I'm sorry to have wasted your time. I think I'll use the approach in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899991/htaccess-rewrite-breaks-relative-paths

Answer (score 0):

Use the following .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

What it does is, redirects all paths and parameters to the index.php.

i.e
if the domain is example.com

so http://example.com/test -> the request will be taken to the index.php file and even if the path if http://example.com/test/another/test

The request will still be taken to the index.php file.

This is the exact same code used by frameworks like laravel.

In the index.php file you can use:

```
$request_uri=parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$path = $request_uri['path'];
```

the `$path` variable will give you the path user entered.