# .htaccess- Changing the URL embedded images on page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I moved a bunch of files to a CDN and wanted all of the existing URLs to redirect to the version on the CDN.

```
RewriteRule images/(.+)$ https://cdn.com/uploads/image/upload/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I used the above configuration, and it does redirects correctly if I access them on the browser directly. But if I try to do it with an embedded HTML image, it just 404s.

Is this possible?

Here is the image tag:

`<img height="50" src="/images/14443/0/thumbnail.jpg">`

Comment: You're probably using relative paths and that makes the rewrite rule give a wrong URL. Can you post a sample `<img>` tag?

Comment: @ishegg `<img height="50" src="/uploads/14443/0/thumbnail.jpg">`

Comment: Yeah, it's the relative path. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899991/htaccess-rewrite-breaks-relative-paths)

Comment: I'm sorry, I was careless when pasting it. Here's the correct example: `<img height="50" src="/images/14673/0/thumbnail.jpg">`

Comment: It's all the same. Did you see the answer I linked?

Comment: @ishegg it works! Thank you so much!